# I have an issue with "minikube start" on Mac machine

Tags: kubernetes, local, minikube

I m trying to start minikube but it is showing as following

minikube start  --vm-driver=virtualbox

minikube v1.5.2 on Darwin 10.13.6
  Downloading VM boot image ...

Failed to cache ISO: https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.5.1.iso: invalid checksum: Error downloading checksum file: Get https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.5.1.iso.sha256: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose

kubectl version

Error in configuration: 
* unable to read client-cert /Users/ashivan2/.minikube/client.crt for minikube due to open /Users/ashivan2/.minikube/client.crt: no such file or directory
* unable to read client-key /Users/ash/.minikube/client.key for minikube due to open /Users/ash/.minikube/client.key: no such file or directory
* unable to read certificate-authority /Users/ashivan2/.minikube/ca.crt for minikube due to open /Users/ash/.minikube/ca.crt: no such file or directory

```
minikube v1.5.2 on Darwin 10.13.6
  Downloading VM boot image ...

  Failed to cache ISO: https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.5.1.iso: invalid checksum: Error downloading checksum file: Get https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.5.1.iso.sha256: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

  Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose


minikube start -p minikube1 --vm-driver=virtualbox
 [minikube1] minikube v1.5.2 on Darwin 10.13.6
  Downloading VM boot image ...

  Failed to cache ISO: https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.5.1.iso: invalid checksum: Error downloading checksum file: Get https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.5.1.iso.sha256: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

  Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose

I m trying to start minikube but it is showing as following and also I used minikube delete and minikube start but no use
```

I m expecting to start minikube in a fine way.
Can anyone help me out in solving the following issue

Comment: Can you please check if firewall is not blocking your connection? Can you test this using proxy?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your machine does not have full access to the internet. Are you running minikube from China by any chance?

You can check by using curl to dowload the ISO: curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v1.5.1.iso

If you aren't able to use the internet, you can download the ISO file to ~/.minikube/cache/iso. You'll also need the appropriate docker images though, so I suggest running minikube start --download-only once from a machine with access to the internet, and copying ~/.minikube/cache over from there.